# Specify modiefied object without passing it in as parameter

Tags: java, class, parameters, instance

being quite new to Java, so please be kind:) In our Java programming Assignment we've got a set of given classes/ interfaces and a specification we should comply with. In some cases, we're allowed to extend the given code, in some we have to strictly leave everything as it is. Now let's get more specific.

We got an interface, let's call it BookshelfService, that can add/ remove/ show the books and authors of the current Bookshelf. There's also a Bookshelf class with methods such as add, remove etc. for books and authors.

The task is that we have to implement a program that interact with the Bookshelf only via the BookshelfService interface. This interface is kind of immutable, we're not allowed to change it, only implement the methods. Those methods of BookshelfService are all of type void, for example:

```
void addAuthor(String name, String email, String id);
```

It's also prescribed that if the User has created or loaded a new Bookshelf via the menu, what is returned from this load/ create-method is NOT directly a Bookshelf, but a BookshelfService, a kind of handle for the Bookshelf.

Now here's the point where I got stuck.

Suppose the user had just created a BookshelfService. Means also we gotta internally call the constructor of the Bookshelf class itself. So far, so good.
The constructor we called looks like this (it's implemented by me, so I might have already there been doing something wrong):

```
public BookshelfService create () {  // my iplementation here  
BookshelfService bookshelfservice = new BookshelfService();  
Bookshelf myBookshelf = new Bookshelf;  
return BookshelfService;  
}
```

But now, imagine we/ the user now wants to insert a new Book or author into the Booksheld. Remember, we're NOT allowed to pass the newly created Bookshelf to the BookshelfService class as an argument. (This would have been my first idea).

How can we tell Java anyway that we want to modify precisely THIS Bookshelf myBookshelf instance we've just created? As fas as I see it, the newly created database will just "die" once the create-Method is finished? So how can we really create a bookshelf-instance that is now accessible from the whole context, for any other method of the BookshelfService we just constructed? And so, if I'd like to immplement the addAuthor-method from above like this:

```
void addAuthor(String name, String email, String id) {  
Author newAuthor = new Author (name, email, string);  
myBookshelf.set(newAuthor);
```

there would be a huge problem: we can't access the myBookshelf instance, as it wasn't keep alive after calling the create-method.

So, did I just overlook something crucial in the way I understood the passing over between classes, methods and so on in Java? Any ideas how I could arrive at my goal of keeping precisely this newly created myBookshelf thing accessible for the BookshelfService as long as this service is running, so that I can modify it by calling the BookshelfService's methods, under the givne constraints?

I'd really appreciate hints and guidance for this puzzle. Thank you.

(Note: to make the Bookshelf a static class is also not possible from the code we've been given with the task...I also had the idea of opening upa totally new BookshelfContext class that would have a static Bookshelf and static BookshelfService variable... and maybe try to tie them together from there on... but it all just relly didn't lead anywhere.

Edit: Okay, so that's what we're allowed/ not allowed to change in detail.

-MainService: both interface and implementation (MainService and MainServiceImpl). Has three methods we're supposed to implement, NO changes/ extensions allowed: Load existing Bookshelf-file (Bookshelf object comes from xml file viaunmarshalling), create new one (, exit.

-BookshelfService: again both an interface and implementation (= BookshelfService and BookshelfServiceImpl), NO changes/ extensions allowed. Has several methods, all void as I showed, for adding/ removing authors/ books, saving/marshalling Objects that were created during program run to a new xml File, etc.

-other classes that I added >> those can be changed. Among them two additional interfaces: MainMenu for selecting from the Options of MainService(Impl), and BookshelfMenu for selecting from the options of BookshelfService.

Comment: You can store the `myBookshelf` as an *instance variable* of `BookshelfService` class

Comment: Ever considered that `Bookshelf` should `implements BookshelfService`? Is that allowed? Anyway, please show more details - a [mcve] to reproduce your specific problem, and indicate which parts you can and cannot change.

Comment: Is the (empty) `BookshelfService` constructor signature something you can’t change?  (If that’s really an `interface`, it doesn’t even have constructors…)

Comment: It is also confusing that you've mentioned that `BookshelfService` is an interface while at the same time you are instantiating it

Comment: @Sweeper: no, for that we'd have to change the signature, and we're not allowed to do that.

Comment: @Davis Herring: Same for the BookshelfService, it's empty constructor can't be changed, and adding a new constructor would also be a change, means it's not allowed.

Comment: @Thiyagu: But for that I'd have to declare a private Bookshelf variable inside of BookshelfService, wouldn't I? (And that again would mean to change the class...)

Comment: I think we have to see the starting point (parts of which cannot be changed).